# how do i pass a pass a arraylist from html page to a servlet in java?

Tags: arraylist

how do i pass a pass a arraylist from html page to a servlet in java?

Answer (score 0):

A HTML page doesn't have any notion of ArrayLists. HTML is a markup language which consists of tags. If you want to send information from the client to the server you could use a `<form>` tag with text fields or AJAX.

Comment: i am sorry.its not a html page.its a servlet displaying html content dynamically.i want to pass a array list from one servlet to another.